# Insert arabic text into an image using Matlab?

Tags: string, matlab, text, unicode, arabic

I'm using this Matlab script to write an arabic text into an image

```
I = imread('test.jpg');
text_str = cell(3,1);
conf_val = [85.212 98.76 78.342];
str = char(['م','ا','ل','س']);
encoded_str = unicode2native(str, 'UTF-8');
position = [23 23];
RGB = insertText(I,position,str);
figure
imshow(RGB)
```

It shows '?' in the image instead of the arabic letters.
[link to result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QXFFO.png)

Comment: I can't replicate. The text shows up fine in R2017a. What `version` are you using? There are several lines of your example code that do nothing.

Comment: i'm using matlab R2015a

Answer (score 1):

This is because by default the character set encoding for m-files is ANSI.
So you can use the [corresponding entities](http://sites.psu.edu/symbolcodes/languages/mideast/arabic/arabicchart/) for the required letters. These entities can be generated using the following in the command window:

```
uint16(['م','ا','ل','س']);        %Thanks to horchler
```

So, you can use:

```
I = imread('office_2.jpg');        %Using a built-in demo image
position = [23 23];                %As given in the question
str = char([1587 1604 1575 1605]); %Converted into the corresponding entities
rgb = insertText(I,position,str);
figure;
imshow(rgb);
```

**Edit:** The problem that you mentioned in the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43392248/insert-arabic-text-into-an-image-using-matlab/43393989#comment73852798_43393989) is reproducible in MATLAB R2015a. You can use [**`AddTextToImage`**](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/40959-add-text-to-image) from the File Exchange. Download and add that to your path. 

And then change `rgb = insertText(I,position,str);` to  `rgb = AddTextToImage(I,str,position);` in the above code.

Comment: Those entities can be automatically generated with `uint16(['م','ا','ل','س'])`.

Comment: in work space the variable has the Arabic text but in displaying  image only a  yellow rectangle empty no more '?' i tried to change the text size but nothing change always the empty rectangle

Comment: @AmineGhozlène Did you try the code as it is given in the answer or did you make some changes?

Comment: Thanks @horchler !

Comment: i tried it without making any change but it doesn't work.